# Google play . Why I have a OpenGL ES 2.0+ not 1.0

Tags: java, android

Hi I am a junior java and android developer I want to put my application to google marker. When my applicaion is loaded in google conseole I see that I have openGL SE 2.0+ And I don't know why my applications is OpenGL ES 2.0+, Why I have this ? I use a lamda expressions and it is my build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'


buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {

        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.22.2'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }

}

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias '***'
            keyPassword '***'
            storeFile file('D:/**.jks')
            storePassword '***'
        }
        defaultConfig {
            buildConfigField "long", "TIMESTAMP", System.currentTimeMillis() + "L"
            buildConfigField 'String', 'BUILD_TIME', 'new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM.dd.yy HH:mm", java.util.Locale.GERMANY).format(new java.util.Date(' + System.currentTimeMillis() + 'L))'

        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "**.***.****"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 48
        versionName "1.4.7"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "armeabi"
        }
        multiDexEnabled true


    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
    sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/'] } }

    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
        force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile(group: 'org.simpleframework', name: 'simple-xml', version: '2.7.1') {
        exclude module: 'stax'
        exclude module: 'stax-api'
        exclude module: 'xpp3'
    }

    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.0'

    compile('io.socket:socket.io-client:1.0.0') {
        // excluding org.json which is provided by Android
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }

    compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '19.0'

    compile group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', name: 'okhttp', version: '3.2.0'
    compile group: 'com.squareup.picasso', name: 'picasso', version: '2.5.0'

    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.8.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:1.1.6@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.5.4@aar'
    compile 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile group: 'joda-time', name: 'joda-time', version: '2.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'
    compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'

}
```

What I have to do , when I want to have a OpenGL ES 1.0+

Comment: probably one of your libraries requires 2.0

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko how I can know which of them requires 2.0 ?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have to read documentation on your libraries.